# Table Space size is increasing too fastly(DEV_MDS in soa suite 11g)

Tags: bpel, soa-suite

I am using Oracle Soa Suite 11g.

We are facing a Data Base (table space)problem. after every deployment schema DEV_MDS is getting increased by 40 MB. we are in development phase so very frequently we are deploying process. 
and while undeploying the process. ideally memory should be reclaimed. but this is not reclaiming the memory.

Please help me to come out from this problem. and it will be appreciated if some one will explain how this schema size is getting increases too fastly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Every time you deploy a composite, artifacts such as process definitions etc. are stored in MDS as a new version. You should purge MDS from time to time.

You can purge it by WLST or from EM. In order to purge from EM;

1. Right click SOA-Infra node under SOA folder
2. In the context menu, select Administration>MDS Configuration
3. At the bottom you can choose number of days to purge and click purge button on the right.

HTH.